# Visual Studio - 'Hover-over' tooltip text without using mouse

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Is there a command to get the 'hover-over' tooltip text to display without using the mouse?

I want for it to pop-up with a keybind if my cursor is currently over it.


(That white block is my cursor).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can see you wants this for Visual Studio 2017. I only know the answer for Visual Studio Code, but mybe they share the same shortcut?

So for Visual Studio Code it is: Ctrl+k Ctrl+i.
This will make the hover information popup.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: That works. In case you want to change that shortcut or bind it somewhere else (e.g. VsVim): the shortcut triggers the VS command `Edit.QuickInfo`